# How to see if section of python code completes within a given time

Tags: python, performance, time

I wish to find out if code (Say a function call) completes within a given time.

For example if I am calling a function with parameters that are elements of an array

```
    #arr1 is some array
    #foo1 is an array that returns something

    for i in range(len(arr1)):
        res1 = foo1(arr1[i])  #calling the function
```

Is there some way by which I can stop foo1 executing and continue with the next iteration of the for loop if foo1 takes more than x seconds to return a value?

Comment: Ideally, `foo1` would support a timeout on its operation.  Barring that, you can spawn another process or thread to execute `foo1` in, and pend (with a timeout) on the results in this main thread.

Comment: Note that if you don't have control over how `foo1` works you'd have to halt the thread which is a downright unsafe idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For stuff like that I normally use the following construct:

```
from threading import Timer
import thread

def run_with_timeout( timeout, func, *args, **kwargs ):
    """ Function to execute a func for the maximal time of timeout.
    [IN]timeout        Max execution time for the func
    [IN]func           Reference of the function/method to be executed
    [IN]args & kwargs  Will be passed to the func call
    """
    try:
        # Raises a KeyboardInterrupt if timer triggers
        timeout_timer = Timer( timeout, thread.interrupt_main )
        timeout_timer.start()
        return func( *args, **kwargs )
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print "run_with_timeout timed out, when running '%s'" %  func.__name__
        #Normally I raise here my own exception
    finally:
        timeout_timer.cancel()
```

Then the call would like:

```
timeout = 5.2 #Time in sec
for i in range(len(arr1)):
    res1 = run_with_timeout(timeout, foo1,arr1[i]))
```

Comment: It works!!!
But can you tell me the units for the timeout (like sec, millisec etc)?

Answer (score 0):

To do this cleanly and correctly, you need cooperation from `foo1()`. If you don't, the best you can do is to run `foo1()` in the context of another process, and to kill that process after a timeout.

Comment: Okay, how do I do that in python?